# Are there some cases where Grover's algorithm was used to improve machine learning performance?

Tags: grovers-algorithm, machine-learning, quantum-advantage

Grover algorithm showing quantum advantage, are there some cases where it was used to improve Machine Learing performance ?

Comment: Are you looking for proposals or actual demonstrations? There currently aren't any quantum computers that can run Grover at a scale that would show significant speedup over classical computers.

Comment: Maybe more like proposals, I thought researchers would have thought about something about it

Answer (score 3):

One way to potentially use Grover's algorithm in machine learning is for the optimization step. Durr and Höyer (1996) proposed a straightforward application: If you have a set $\Theta$ parameters and a loss function $L: \Theta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to optimize. Then suppose you have oracle access to a cost-comparison function $C:\Theta\times \Theta \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that $C(\theta, \theta') = 1$ if $L(\theta) < L(\theta')$ and $C(\theta, \theta')=0$ otherwise. This gives you a way to "mark" all solutions to $L$ that are better than $\theta'$. Now if you start with a state
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{|\Theta|^{1/2}} \sum_{\theta \in \Theta} |\theta\rangle |\theta_{current}\rangle,
\end{equation}
then you can do a series of Grover searches using $C$ as the oracle and iteratively updating $\theta_{current}$ to the output of the previous search; after enough iterations $\theta_{current}$ will contain the minimizer $\text{argmin}_{\theta \in \Theta} L(\theta)$.

This has obvious practical problems: Oracle access to a complicated cost function like this is trouble, and this provides only a square-root speedup over what could be an exponentially large search space (e.g. if $\Theta$ is the discretization of a continuous parameter space). But there are a few methods inspired by this technique that don't have such obvious disadvantages - see ([Wiebe, 2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2142)) and ([Aïmeur, 2012](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-012-5316-5)).

Section III of ([Liao, 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.17047)) and Chapter 7.2 of ([Schuld and Petruccione, 2021](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-83098-4)) have some more discussion of this kind of approach that you may find useful.

Comment: +1. But I wonder how many  millions of qubits it will take to fault  tolerantly implement an oracle for a simple loss function for image classification.